# How to inspect `request.remote_ip`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request

I want trigger an action from another server. This is the code for it in controller.

```
  def trigger_from_remote
    if request.remote_ip == ENV['REMOTE_SERVER_IP']
      # Do something
    end
    head 200, content_type: 'text/html'
  end
```

This code works if there is no if statement. So `request.remote_ip == ENV['REMOTE_SERVER_IP']` must be the problem.

I confirmed the `ENV['REMOTE_SERVER_IP']` has a right value in rails console, but I couln't figure out how to check if `request.remote_ip` has right value.

If it's not about request I can use `binding.pry` in local environement.

How can I check the `request.remote_ip` value interactively?

Comment: Check the datatype of both the request.remote_ip & ENV['REMOTE_SERVER_IP']

Comment: you can see it in log file

Comment: you can do this for logging `p "HI---------=======>>>#{request.remote_ip} AND #{request.remote_ip.class}"`

Comment: Actually it's not a datatype case:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Request/remote_ip

Check the method implementation, it always return string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your best bit is to make sure that `request.remote_ip` value is equals to `ENV['REMOTE_SERVER_IP']`

As a quick workaround for inspection you can do this (ugly but works):

```
def trigger_from_remote
  Rails.logger.info "<<DEBUG: #{request.remote_ip} || #{ENV['REMOTE_SERVER_IP']}"
  .
  .
end
```

Then in your server (assume it's the staging server):

```
app_directory$ tail -f log/staging.log | grep DEBUG
```

Of course, make sure that the `config.log_level` is `info` for example.

Comment: Great! I could see `ENV['REMOTE_SERVER_IP']` if I use `rails console`, but the environment variable is not loaded `unicorn` instance. After restart `unicorn` instance it works fine.